# Restriction of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ open and $D\subset U$ an open disk of radius $r>0$ centered at $z_0\in U$.
When is the restriction map $f\rightarrow f_{|D}:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ of a holomorphic function $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ to holomorphic functions on $D$ injectiv, when surjectiv?

Comment: Injectivity is given in any case due to the identity theorem (an open disk $D$ has a limit point).

Comment: @Valentin the only assumption is that $f$ is holomorphic on $U$. How is injectivity given in any case?

Comment: @AhmedHussein Assuming $U$ is connected, then the identity theorem gives injectivity, as Valentin already stated.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud the (poorly written) question appears to be asking: "when is the restriction of a holomorphic function $f: U \to \Bbb C$ to an open disk $D \subset U$ an injective function?". Are you guys saying that holomorphic functions on connected sets are injective?! There are many obvious counterexamples to this. Otherwise, what is the question asking?

Comment: @AhmedHussein No, the question is asking "when is the *restriction map* injective".

Comment: @AhmedHussein No, it's not about the restricted map but it's all about the _restriction map_.

Comment: Note that "injective" means any restricted map can be uniquely extended from $D$ to $U$ (and this requires some connectivity), while "surjective" means any holomorphic map on $D$ has some extension to $U$.  The latter is never possible if the inclusion $D\subset U$ is proper, since a function on the disk can have a singularity on the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

I correct my previous answer in the comment: Injectivity is given iff $D$ intersects all connected components of $U$. The identity theorem states that a function defined on a set $A$ with a limit point determines every extension of this function to a connected set $B$ containing $A$.  Now if we assume $f|_D=g|_D$ we must have $f=g$ on every connected component in $U$ and hence on $U$.

Surjectivity is given iff the connected component of $U$ containing $D$ is actually equal to $D$. Because otherwise there is a point $z_0\in U\cap \bar{D}$ but not in $D$. Define now $f(z)=1/(z-z_0)$ in $D$ (well-defined). This function does not extend holomorphically to $U$.

Comment: In particular for connected $U$, we get injectivity in any case and surjectivity iff $D=U$.